# AngularUniversal prerendering error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'class{}'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, express, angular-universal

### Goal

Question looks long winded - it's not!

I'm using Angular Universal to implement SSR, following this [tutorial](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-universal/). Universal/express-engine is installed, `main.js` is generated in the `dist/projectname/server` folder, and I've created a `prerender.js` folder in the project root.

### Problem

When I try `npm run prerender` it starts work prerendering until eventually hitting the following error:

```
Prerendering 5 route(s) to C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\browser
(node:27236) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'class{}'.
    at NgModuleResolver.resolve (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:628845)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:603430)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:672203)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:671712)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:670635)
    at useClass.compileModuleAsync (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:2063708)
    at compileNgModuleFactory__PRE_R3__ (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:1372200)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:1376714)
    at renderModule (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:2085795)
    at C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\node_modules\@nguniversal\builders\src\prerender\render.js:66:32
(node:27236) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:28592) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'class{}'.
    at NgModuleResolver.resolve (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:628845)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:603430)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:672203)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:671712)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:670635)
    at useClass.compileModuleAsync (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:2063708)
    at compileNgModuleFactory__PRE_R3__ (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:1372200)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:1376714)
    at renderModule (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:2085795)
    at C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\node_modules\@nguniversal\builders\src\prerender\render.js:66:32
(node:1236) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'class{}'.
    at NgModuleResolver.resolve (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:628845)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:603430)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:672203)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:671712)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:670635)
    at useClass.compileModuleAsync (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:2063708)
    at compileNgModuleFactory__PRE_R3__ (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:1372200)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:1376714)
    at renderModule (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:2085795)
    at C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\node_modules\@nguniversal\builders\src\prerender\render.js:66:32
(node:27236) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:28592) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1236) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:29420) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'class{}'.
    at NgModuleResolver.resolve (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:628845)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:603430)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:672203)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:671712)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:670635)
    at useClass.compileModuleAsync (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:2063708)
    at compileNgModuleFactory__PRE_R3__ (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:1372200)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:1376714)
    at renderModule (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:2085795)
    at C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\node_modules\@nguniversal\builders\src\prerender\render.js:66:32
(node:32908) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'class{}'.
    at NgModuleResolver.resolve (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:628845)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:603430)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:672203)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:671712)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:670635)
    at useClass.compileModuleAsync (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:2063708)
    at compileNgModuleFactory__PRE_R3__ (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:1372200)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:1376714)
    at renderModule (C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\dist\hibernio\server\main.js:1:2085795)
    at C:\Users\odubh\Documents\Personal_Web_Projects\Hibernio.com\Hibernio0.3\hibernio\node_modules\@nguniversal\builders\src\prerender\render.js:66:32
(node:28592) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:1236) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:29420) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:32908) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:29420) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:32908) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

### Desired Outcome

Pre-render the HTML of our main HTML route , and output it to a text file.

### What I've Tried

[This](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/angular/angular-cli/11218/541244312): delete the chained `.catch(err...)` function of the bootstrap in `main.ts` - same error

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55320181/no-ngmodule-metadata-found-for-appmodule-after-upgrade-from-angular-5-to-angul): delete node-modules, package.json, run `npm install`, `ng build`, `ng serve` - same error, also `package.json` didn't regenerate like the answer suggested and I thought I nuked my app

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47497052/no-ngmodule-metadata-found-for-appmodule): Update AngularCLI and Webpack - same error

### Versions

```
Angular CLI: 10.0.0
Node: 12.16.3
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 10.0.0
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server
... router
Ivy Workspace: <error>

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.900.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.9
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.9
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.9
@angular-devkit/core              9.0.7
@angular-devkit/schematics        10.0.0
@angular/cdk                      9.2.4
@angular/fire                     6.0.2
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.9
@nguniversal/builders             9.1.1
@nguniversal/common               9.1.1
@nguniversal/express-engine       9.1.1
@schematics/angular               10.0.0
@schematics/update                0.1000.0
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.9.5
webpack                           4.43.0
```

### Files

1. prerender.ts

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import {renderModuleFactory} from '@angular/platform-server';
import {writeFileSync} from 'fs';

const {AppServerModuleNgFactory} = require('./dist/hibernio/server/main');


renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
    document: '<app-root></app-root>',
    url: '/'
})
.then(html => {
    console.log('Pre-rendering successful, saving prerender.html');
    writeFileSync('./prerender.html', html);
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error('Error occurred:', error);
});
```

2. server.ts

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app() {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/hibernio/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run() {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

3. main.server.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

export { AppServerModule } from './app/app.server.module';
export { renderModule, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
```

4. tsconfig.server.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app-server",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.server.ts",
    "server.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "./src/app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
  }
}
```

5. angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "hibernio": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/hibernio/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css",
              "node_modules/ngx-sharebuttons/themes/circles/circles-dark-theme.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "hibernio:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "hibernio:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "hibernio:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "hibernio:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "hibernio:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "deploy": {
          "builder": "@angular/fire:deploy",
          "options": {}
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/hibernio/server",
            "main": "server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "outputHashing": "media",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "sourceMap": false,
              "optimization": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve-ssr": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "hibernio:build",
            "serverTarget": "hibernio:server"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "hibernio:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "hibernio:server:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "prerender": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "hibernio:build:production",
            "serverTarget": "hibernio:server:production",
            "routes": [
              "/"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "hibernio"
}
```

6. package.json

```
{
  "name": "hibernio",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run hibernio:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/hibernio/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build --prod && ng run hibernio:server:production",
    "prerender": "ng run hibernio:prerender"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.7",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.6.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.29",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.13.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.1",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^9.1.1",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "mdbootstrap": "^4.19.0",
    "ngx-sharebuttons": "^8.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.7",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^9.1.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.38",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.900",
    "firebase-tools": "^8.0.0",
    "fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
    "inquirer": "^6.2.2",
    "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

### Update

David spotted Ivy had an error. I then enabled Ivy in `tsconfig.json` > `compilerOptions` > `enableIvy`, and it threw a stack of errors re fontawesome:

```
Warning: Invalid constructor parameter decorator in C:/Users/odubh/Documents/Personal_Web_Projects/Hibernio.com/Hibernio0.3/hibernio/node_modules/angular-font-awesome/dist/angular-font-awesome.js:
 function () { return [
    { type: LocationStrategy, },
]; }
```

I previously had to disable Ivy when implementing fontawesome, as they seemed to cause errors together and the StackOverflow solution seemed to be to disable Ivy. Now I need Ivy to implement Universal and I'm at a loss for what to do to get both of these packages to work together - preferably with Ivy enabled as this seems recommended.

Thanks David for spotting the Ivy problem.

Comment: Your info says `Ivy Workspace: <error>`, so maybe it's because of this. Also, I don't think you need a `prerender.ts` file, you can just add the routes in `angular.json` file, in `prerender` target

Comment: @David thanks for that! You could be right. I changed `tsconfig.json` file `compilerOptions > enableIvy` to true, and it threw another massive error `Warning: Invalid constructor parameter decorator in C:/Users/odubh/Documents/Personal_Web_Projects/Hibernio.com/Hibernio0.3/hibernio/node_modules/angular-font-awesome/dist/angular-font-awesome.js:
 function () { return [
    { type: LocationStrategy, },
]; }` - I had previously disabled Ivy because it was incompatible with fontawesome, which I was implementing. Any idea how I can get Ivy, fontawesome and Universal to work together?

Comment: Try updating your post with the error

Comment: That's weird, because I'm using font awesome and angular universal together without any issue. Try clearing and reinstall node modules. The angular-font-awesome module should be inside @fortawesome folder

Comment: I followed this suggestion and it results in the same error :( If it means anything, I'm also using ngx-sharebuttons and Firebase (in case you're aware of any issues?)

Comment: Check my answer. You should not have the same error if you uninstall the deprecated package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable Ivy to get rid of the first problem (`No NgModule found ...`).

For the 2nd one (`Invalid constructor parameter decorator`), the reason is probably that you are using `angular-font-awesome`, which is not maintained anymore and does not work with Ivy

So uninstall that package (`npm uninstall angular-font-awesome -S`) and keep only the `fortawesome` packages:

```
"@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.6.1",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.1",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.29",
"@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.13.1",
"@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.1",
```

**Note**: Like I said in my comment, I do not think that you need to create the `prerender.ts` file. You can just add routes to render to `angular.json` and run `ng run prerender`

Comment: Thank you Sir! That's fixed the error! The learning curve in angular/node is massive. I feel like I could trawl through documentation for weeks and still not have understood the issue. Is there a certain way we should check whether a package is maintained or not before deciding to use it? I went to the `angular-font-awesome` npmjs page (www.npmjs.com/package/angular-font-awesome) and there's no warning to let me know it comes with such risks. Thanks again for helping me out!

Comment: What you can do before deciding to install a package is go to the github repo and check there if it's maintained or if there are roo many unsolved issues