# Error with angular srr prerendering with ngx-paypal

Tags: angular, typescript, paypal, angular-universal, prerender

Trying to implement prerender on my angular 9 project but I get this error

When I run **prerender**

```
Prerendering 9 route(s) to C:\Users\Khaled\Desktop\MechatronicsSmartSolutions\dist\MechatronicsSmartSolutions\browser
(node:11896) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'class{}'.
```

Following this solution I have to **enable ivy**

[AngularUniversal prerendering error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'class{}'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62586525/angularuniversal-prerendering-error-unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-error-no)

But in this case I get this error from **ngx-paypal**

*""This likely means that the library (ngx-paypal) which declares NgxPayPalModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.""*

Tried reinstalling NPM modules didn't make any difference

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.5",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.6.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^9.1.1",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.2.6",
    "emailjs-com": "^2.6.3",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "firebase": "^7.6.0",
    "ngx-owl-carousel-o": "^3.1.1",
    "ngx-page-scroll": "^7.0.3",
    "ngx-page-scroll-core": "^7.0.3",
    "ngx-pagination": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-paypal": "^6.2.0",
    "ngx-spinner": "^9.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.5",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^9.1.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  }
```

Comment: try building your project using angular cli and check it again - ng build project_name;

Comment: Tried it, no difference

Comment: try to update @angular-devkit/build-angular to the latest version

Comment: Please update your question with" main.ts" as well as "app.module.ts" file that's going to be a easy for everyone to understand it better.